# Installing Flutter on Mac OS

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

on running flutter doctor i get the below dependency lacking :

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
     Could not determine java version
Android Studio (not installed)
```

But i have already installed both and developing apps on Android Studio.Then why flutter is not able to find these two?

It is complaining for the jre version as well.But internally Android Studio uses the jre which is already installed with it.

flutter doctor -v gives below output :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /Users/<myusername>/Downloads/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/<myusername>/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK at /Users/<myusername>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: What Android Studio version did you install?

Comment: My android studio version is 3.2.1

Comment: It is complaining for the jre version as well. Can you please post the full `flutter doctor -v` output?

Comment: Did you installed the flutter plugin on Android Studio?

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo NO i didnt install yet.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer added the flutter doctor verbose output

Comment: What Java version did you install? `java --version`?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3879451

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer java --version opens up a pop with ok and more info options.On clicking the more info it leads me to oracle site to download the java.I did that and on installing the java (clicking the .dmg ) it opens up a windows that it is installing java and at the en it says "successfully installed java 8 update 201" , but i am not sure where it has installed it? java --version still opens up the same pop up

Comment: Shouldn't matter. What does `flutter doctor -v` print now? Restart your system if it prints the same as before, then try again and let us know what the result is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did restart .Updated the flutter doctor -v output above !

Comment: Looks much better now already. What do you now get for `java -version`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No Java runtime present, requesting install.
and the same window ! I think i need to install jre??is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188296/discussion-between-raulp-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I had the same issue, I end up Unistalling and Intalling Android Studio again

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Xcode:

Install Xcode (get it from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Ensure Xcode app is in the /Applications directory (NOT /Users/{user}/Applications).

Point xcode-select to the Xcode app Developer directory using the following command:
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Note: Make sure your Xcode app path is correct.

Xcode: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Xcode-beta: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer